# I want to make that the button could be used only by the author of the message

Tags: button, discord.py, bots

```
class HangmanButton(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, *, timeout=180):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)


    @discord.ui.button(label="Начать Игру", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray)
    async def button(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_modal(HangmanStartModal())
```

`if interaction.user is not interaction.creator.author: return await interaction.response.send_message(embed = discord.Embed(title='❌| Ошибка', description='Вы не можете играть в своей собственной игре.', color=discord.Color.darker_grey()), ephemeral=True)`

## I used something like this but it doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by `author of the message`? The author of the message that has the UI components will be the bot... Do you mean the user that triggered the command that sent the message with the buttons?

Comment: Yes, the person who called the command @ESloman

Answer (score 1):

[discord.Interaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.Interaction) doesn't have an attribute called `creator`. To get the original author you can take an argument. Then, you can override discord's check with your own `interaction_check`.

```
class HangmanButton(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, author, timeout=180):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
        self.author = author


    @discord.ui.button(label="Начать Игру", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray)
    async def button(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_modal(HangmanStartModal())

    async def interaction_check(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        return interaction.user.id == self.author.id
```

Hence, when calling your view:

```
@tree.command()
async def testcommand(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    view = HangmanButton(interaction.user) # or ctx.author/message.author where applicable
    await interaction.response.send_message(view=view)
```

Comment: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'author'
Command found error @Raymus

Comment: The code takes a positional argument 'author', so when calling the view, include the command author. If it is an application command, it would be `interaction.user`. If it is a regular command, it would be `ctx.author`. If it is an `on_message` event, it would be `message.author`.

Comment: I've edited my answer to make it look clearer when used in a command